# Using `limited with` in Ada to avoid circular dependency

Tags: ada

I'm trying to get a couple of `task`s to be able to call each other, but I don't seem very good with this `limited with` thing..

I have a spec `sctrain-trains.ads`

```
limited with SCTrain.Stations;
with SCTrain.Travellers, SCTrain.Tracks, Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
use SCTrain.Travellers, SCTrain.Tracks, Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

package SCTrain.Trains is
   type my_station_access_t is access all Stations.Station;

   task type Train is
      entry Start(leaving: my_station_access_t; arriving: my_station_access_t);
   end Train;

end SCTrain.Trains;
```

and its `.adb`

```
with SCTrain.Stations;
use SCTrain.Stations;

package body SCTrain.Trains is

   task body Train is
      destination: my_station_access_t;
   begin
      accept Start(leaving: my_station_access_t; arriving: my_station_access_t) do
         destination := arriving;
      end Start;
      destination.Gogo(1);
   end Train;

end SCTrain.Trains;
```

I found in the documents I've been reading that `with`ing the "circular" package in the body would allow smooth executions, but apparently I still have an `invalid prefix in selected component "destination"` because `dereference must not be of an incomplete type (RM 3.10.1)`, and those errors stay there even without the `with` and `use` in the package body.
I'm sure I'm missing something, possibly something very basic, and I'd really love to know what that is. The problem I'm trying to solve is that the Train needs a signal from the Station to be allowed to leave and still able to communicate its arrival time afterwards.

I'm using the latest GNAT-GPL.

Thank you very much.

edit: adding `Station`'s code

```
limited with SCTrain.Trains;
with Ada.Calendar, Ada.Strings.Unbounded, Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Calendar, Ada.Strings.Unbounded, Ada.Text_IO;

package SCTrain.Stations is

   task type Station is
      entry Gogo(name_d : Integer := 0);
   end Station;

end SCTrain.Stations;
```

and the body:

```
with SCTrain.Trains;
use SCTrain.Trains;

package body SCTrain.Stations is
   task body Station is
      name  : Integer;
   begin
      accept Gogo (name_d : Integer := 0) do
         name := name_d;
         Put_Line("Station " & Integer'Image(name) & " is alive");
      end Gogo;
   end Station;

end SCTrain.Stations;
```

Comment: Does your SCTrain.Stations.Station task have a discriminant? That would make it an incomplete type. If that is the case, try adding a default value to the discriminant.

Comment: It does not, but thanks for the good guess; I was playing around with the initial rendezvous to make sure that it would work afterwards.

Comment: Try using a `limited with` in one direction only, and a normal `with` in the other.

Comment: Well that worked, how embarrassing.. I also tried mirroring the behaviour on the Station (receiving an `access` variable to a Train and trying calling an `entry` on it) and that worked as well. I'm sure I read today that having more than one was not an issue, but I guess you never know.. Thanks a lot, if you convert your comment in an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: See also [*Rationale for Ada 2005: 4.2 Mutually dependent types*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-4-2.html),

Comment: Yes I saw that, multiple times: that's where I read that `If we have a cycle of packages we only have to put limited with on one package since that is sufficient to break the cycle of dependences. However, for symmetry, in this example we have made them both have a limited view of each other.` And that's why I wasn't really concerned about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `limited with` in one direction only, and a normal `with` in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the declaration of `destination` by

```
destination: access Stations.Station;
```

or replace the offending line by

```
destination.all.Gogo(1);
```

I don't know whether this is a compiler bug or proper behaviour; it looks suspicious!

Later: I posted a still-more-cut-down example on comp.lang.ada and one of the resident experts agrees that it's a bug; I'll report it to AdaCore.

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug to me.  The designated type of my_station_access_t is an incomplete type (since it's in a `limited with`ed package), but 3.10.1(2.1-2.6) makes it clear that when it's dereferenced, if the full view of the type is visible at that point then the dereference refers to the full view.  That should be true whether the dereference is explicit or implicit (see 4.1(8)).

Comment: @ajb: yes, all the examples use anonymous access types; and I expect that the only reason they're not used here is that they aren't allowed as `entry` parameters. Probably this usage is't in the test set.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up to proper developers, I also enjoyed reading comments to the project's diagram :)